# set position of imageview in recyclerview onBindViewHolder method

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-recyclerview

i have set imageview resource through checking true or false value from database in recyclerview.
but every time i got the last value from database,,My query is how to set position vise image resource in imageView.?
please help me to set position of imageview.

Thanks in Advance..

My Code is

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Menu_List_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    //  progressDialog.show();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TableName");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                for (ParseObject parseObject : objects)
                {
                    if (parseObject != null)
                    {
                        Title = (String) parseObject.get("Name");
                        Description = (String) parseObject.get("Desc");
                        Nut = (Boolean) parseObject.get("IsNut");
                        holder.TVTitle.setText(mItems.get(position).title);
                        TVDescription.setText(mItems.get(position).description);

                        if (Nut == true)
                            holder.IMGNut.setImageResource(R.drawable.nut);
                        else
                            holder.IMGNut.setImageResource(R.drawable.nut_gray);
                    }
                }else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: before set image resource first clear the previous resources

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position vise make a singleton class which store all the values and also clear IMGNut resources before sitting new resources

```
 holder.IMGNut.setBackgroundResource(0);//clear previous resources
if (Nut) {
 holder.IMGNut.setImageResource(R.drawable.nut);
}else{
 holder.IMGNut.setImageResource(R.drawable.nut_gray);
}
```

Comment: because you did not make singletion class in order to store position